# модуль requests не использует прокси

Tags: python, requests

Создал прокси через 3proxy, в проксифаере и браузере работает корректно. А в программе в ответ на запрос получаю свой истинный адрес. Долго копался, однажды выдало адрес прокси, перезапустил и все стало по прежнему. Если верить логам из 3proxy, то программа даже не отправляет запрос к прокси.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth

InfoIP = [2.2, "-----------\n"]
InfoIP2 = [2.2, "b\n"]

proxies = {'http': '192.326.3.16:3228'}

auth = HTTPProxyAuth("asdsad", "asdsa")

ip = requests.get("https://icanhazip.com/", proxies=proxies, auth=auth, verify=False, timeout=10).text

InfoIP[0] = ip.replace("\n", '')
InfoIP2[0] = ip.replace("\n", '')

print(f'{InfoIP}{InfoIP2}')
```

Comment: Попробуйте прописать порты

Comment: не подскажешь как?

Comment: Упс. они у вас уже прописаны. Простити мою неуклюжую не внимательность.

Comment: проксифаер я так понимаю что это отдельная прога. Мои предположения раз в проксифаер и браузере прокси работают (если трафик идет через ихний прокси-сервер), значит они точно знают что вы не браузер или проксифаер. Значить надо закосить под браузер

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1397166/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-http-%d0%b2-python