# Почему прокси не работает через http в python?

Tags: python, requests, proxy

Проблема в том что, если использовать http, то программа игнорирует прокси(проверял на нескольких), в ответ на запрос к сайту получаю свой истинный адрес. Если использовать https, то 1 прокси с авторизацией работает. Второй, который я поднял через 3proxy, в логах показывает, что запрос к нему приходит без данных для авторизации и соответственно соединение заканчивается ошибкой. Если авторизацию отключить, то работает исправно. Почему не использует данные для авторизации и почему не работает через http? Может возможно строго задать использование прокси с http и строго задать данные для авторизации?

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth

InfoIP = [2.2, "-----------\n"]
InfoIP2 = [2.2, "b\n"]

proxies = {'http': '192.326.3.16:3228'}

auth = HTTPProxyAuth("asdsad", "asdsa")

ip = requests.get("https://icanhazip.com/", proxies=proxies, auth=auth, verify=False, timeout=10).text

InfoIP[0] = ip.replace("\n", '')
InfoIP2[0] = ip.replace("\n", '')

print(f'{InfoIP}{InfoIP2}')
```

Answer (score 0):

proxies = {'http': '192.**326**.3.16:3228'}  может тут проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Решил не придумывать. Заменил авторизацию логин/пароль на авторизацию по ip и через https подключаюсь.